# Failed to send notification from firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[This](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/) is some tutorial of firebase. I'm registering app in Firebase, getting the google-services.json file, pasting it in the app files as shown in the tutorial. Also getting the token. But when I'm trying to send notification from console, the status is failed (I guess MismatchSenderId). I'm inserting the same token that I got from `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`. What can be the problem?

p.s. When I send notification to all devices that uses the app, it didn't succeed too.

**EDIT:**  Manifest File

```
<!-- Adding Internet Permission -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
        Defining Services
    -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: can you share your android manifest file that will be much helpful ?

Comment: Manifest share done.

Comment: No problem with your manifest. it looks good. Did you update your developer console with the SHA 1 fingerprint. Are you using Signed APK or debug one. In both the cases you need to update the console with fingerprints.

Comment: I updated console with SHA1 , and using debug apk.

Comment: did you able to send the notification from FCM console. Try sending the notification fcm console. While sending try closing your app and check.

Comment: first of all I tried to send from FCM console, but didn;t succeed, it shows failed. I tried while app was closed, but status was the same "Failed". Also tried to send from server and got MismatchSenderId error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117204/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-hayk-nahapetyan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kindly check if all the below conditions were satisfied.

> 1. Update the SHA 1 finger print and package name in your console.
> 2. Place a json configuration file from the developer console and place it under app directory [module level directory].
> 3. Add these lines in the gradle files.
>      a) Module gradle : apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
>      b) Project gradle : classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Hope it helps you...

Comment: My problem was that I put google-settings.json in wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you're not add a correct SHA1 for your application?
you can follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) to get the correct SHA1. And then on console firebase choose project setting, choose add SHA1. After that, you need to replace google-services.json with the newest one.

Comment: yes, it is for oauth authentification, you can check in google-services.json, there is a field called "certificate_hash". Owh, and the password for default.keystore is "android"