# After registering app with FCM, the notification is not sent to device either when the app is in foreground or background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After creating a notification for device it is in processing state rather than send:

[image: 1]

Comment: can your provide the code for the class where you extends `FirebaseMessagingService`

Comment: @Sirisha Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38352326/2078074) before sending push notification from Firebase console. Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this services in your `Manifest` File,

```
  <service android:name=".service.FireBaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".service.FireBaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Annd use this classes,

```
public class FireBaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

And Receive your notification in this class

```
public class FireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
Bitmap bitmap, icon;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
```