# How to solve error "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH" error Using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification to a device, but I get this error, what does it means?, I find this note in the documentation:

> The authenticated sender ID is different from the sender ID for the
>   registration token.

but I do not really understand.

Here is this explanation in the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode

Comment: This answer helped me to solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338179/failed-to-send-notification-from-firebase-console

Comment: Check the registration token you're sending the message to. Is it really associated with the project you're sending the message from?

Comment: I already solved the problem, when trying to send message directly from the "Firebase Cloud Messaging" console it was not working, so I changed the settings o the (Android) project there, sha1 fingerprint, package Name, and update the json file on Android project and it worked.